# Is there any way to perform regularization in sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I wonder if there's any way to perform regularization in sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB by throwing param like in sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier or sklearn.svm.SVC?

Comment: Please RTM: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.